# Will related posts shown on Mobile but hidden for PC via css harm SEO?

Tags: seo

I have mobile layout which drastically differs from PC as I have Related content displayed at the bottom of page for mobile but not for PC. Will it harm SEO if I hide related posts on PC via css and display only on Mobile ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it will harm SEO? Is it a duplicate content?

Comment: I think it may consider it as hidden content....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when someone click on that related content the user are automatically redirected on mobile version of website, also make sure that content for mobile is same as for PC, also use same URL's. To fix duplicate content issue just add canonical tag on mobile version of site. I recommend using separate domain for mobile like m.example.com

Comment: The Google recommended mobile method is responsive design (one URL) and Bing want one URL. Therefore, separate domain is not to be recommended though Google can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Not, it will not hurt your SEO. Google uses what is displayed for desktop to compute mobile rankings (more details in a [summary](https://seosummaries.com/expertise/mobile-site-seo-tips-strategy.html) I maintain).

However, it is not recommended to display more content in mobile than in desktop.